# famo.us/js: bind dynamic data to click event for emitting data

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, bind, famo.us

I'd like to bind click events to surfaces which I collected in an array.
Every time a click is fired, I'd like to emit a message. But every click should emit it's own data. I know I have a problem with the scope but I couldn't figure out how to solve it :(

```
for(var i=0; i < clickableSurfaces.length; i++) {
    clickableSurfaces[i].on('click', function() {
       // output: undefined
       console.log(this.options[i]);
            
       // output: desired data
       console.log(this.options[0]);
       
        // emit data another view
       this._eventOutput.emit('foo', {data: this.options[i]});
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Somehow I have to get the `i` variable to work inside of `.on(...)` but binding it (`.bind(this, i)`) didn't work.
Does anyone know how to solve it or could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to bind the data when you setup the listener.  This way you are not worried about the index value of the object passed.

```js
for(var i=0; i < clickableSurfaces.length; i++) {
    clickableSurfaces[i].on('click', function(data, event) {
        // data = this.options[i]
        console.log(data);

        // emit data to another view
        // this = anotherView in this case
        this._eventOutput.emit('foo', {data: data});
    }.bind(anotherView, this.options[i]));
}

anotherView.on('foo', function(event) {
    // event.data was emitted with the event
    console.log(event.data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes you are right. That looks and sounds like a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: You not only have to bind the "i" to the event, you also have to assign the parameter "i" to the function.

Full code:

```
for(var i=0; i < clickableSurfaces.length; i++) {
clickableSurfaces[i].on('click', function(**i**) {
   // output: undefined
   console.log(this.options[i]);

   // output: desired data
   console.log(this.options[0]);

    // emit data another view
   this._eventOutput.emit('foo', {data: this.options[i]});
}.bind(this, **i**));
}
```